# count number of emails sent using smtplib python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail-api, google-sheets-api, smtplib

I have a basic python code that sends out an email to addresses from a list in Google sheet.

I want to count the number of times an email is sent to a particular email address by the python script. I tried researching on it. I didn't find anything related to it. And being a complete beginner hasn't helped me make much progress.

If anyone can point me to a particular direction that would be super helpful. Thanks so much in advance.

Below is the code

```
import smtplib
import ssl
from email.mime.text import MIMEText  # New line
from email.utils import formataddr  # New line

# User configuration
sender_email = 'email ID'
sender_name = 'name'
password = "password"

receiver_emails = [RECEIVER_EMAIL_1, RECEIVER_EMAIL_2, RECEIVER_EMAIL_3]
receiver_names = [RECEIVER_NAME_1, RECEIVER_NAME_2, RECEIVER_NAME_3]

# Email text
email_body = '''
    This is a test email sent by Python. Isn't that cool?
'''

for receiver_email, receiver_name in zip(receiver_emails, receiver_names):
    print("Sending the email...")

    # Configurating user's info
    msg = MIMEText(email_body, 'plain')
    msg['To'] = formataddr((receiver_name, receiver_email))
    msg['From'] = formataddr((sender_name, sender_email))
    msg['Subject'] = 'Hello, my friend ' + receiver_name

    try:
        # Creating a SMTP session | use 587 with TLS, 465 SSL and 25
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        # Encrypts the email
        context = ssl.create_default_context()
        server.starttls(context=context)
        # We log in into our Google account
        server.login(sender_email, password)
        # Sending email from sender, to receiver with the email body
        server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, msg.as_string())
        print('Email sent!')

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Oh no! Something bad happened!n {e}')

    finally:
        print('Closing the server...')
        server.quit()
```

Comment: Could you share your code please?

Comment: Updated with code

Comment: And you want to count number of times each address (receiver_email) was sent successfully?

Comment: yes, that's correct. emails sent successfully by the script to each address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a list of successful emails, which will be populated on each iteration and then, use `Counter` from `collections` module, which receives an iterable and returns an object with number of occurrences of each element in the iterable.
You can try the following code:

```
from collections import Counter
import json

counter_file_path = "counter.json"
try:
    with open(counter_file_path, "r") as f:
        email_stats = json.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError as ex:
        email_stats = {}

successful_emails = []
for receiver_email, receiver_name in zip(receiver_emails, receiver_names):
    print("Sending the email...")

    # Configurating user's info
    msg = MIMEText(email_body, 'plain')
    msg['To'] = formataddr((receiver_name, receiver_email))
    msg['From'] = formataddr((sender_name, sender_email))
    msg['Subject'] = 'Hello, my friend ' + receiver_name

    try:
        # Creating a SMTP session | use 587 with TLS, 465 SSL and 25
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        # Encrypts the email
        context = ssl.create_default_context()
        server.starttls(context=context)
        # We log in into our Google account
        server.login(sender_email, password)
        # Sending email from sender, to receiver with the email body
        server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, msg.as_string())
        print('Email sent!')
        if receiver_email in email_stats:
            email_stats[receiver_email] += 1
        else:
            email_stats[receiver_email] = 1
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Oh no! Something bad happened!n {e}')

    finally:
        print('Closing the server...')
        server.quit()

print(email_stats) # output - all occurrences for each email 
with open(counter_file_path, "w") as f:
     json.dump(email_stats, f)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will give it a try.

Comment: Hi, so this worked to a certain effect. I was wondering if there is a way to count up the successful email sent to each ID. For eg: Let's say the script sends an email to "abc@email.com" twice. So it should reflect 2. And then once again it sends successfully so the count should increase to 3 and so on. Currently, it shows just 1 for each iteration. Also, I wanted to save the count to Google sheet. How can I convert the number to a string format which can be saved easily in Google sheet?

Comment: Do you want to count the occurrences between different runs of the script? @SouravChatterjee

Comment: Yes. That's how I want it to count.

Comment: ok, so you should save the counter results to a file or db and update them on each run. I've updated the solution with saving the counter results to a json file that will be updated on each run. This file will be loaded in the beginning of each run to `email_stats` variable, will be updated during the run, and saved again when the script finishes.

Comment: Hi, I am having an error in this `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'counter.json'` How can I fix this?

Comment: Sure! Please consider upvote/accept the answer, if it helped you, in order to help other developers struggling with similar issue...

Comment: Hi, how can I transfer values from the JSON to a Google Sheet directly from the script or save the values directly to a Google Sheet instead of the JSON file? Any suggestion or direction you can point me towards? I have tried looking around. I haven't found any suitable answers for it.

Comment: @SouravChatterjee one way to do so is to read your json into pandas dataframe and write it to google sheets using google api. Here you can find an example for reading and writing from/to google sheets: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-read-and-write-data-to-google-spreadsheet-using-python-ebf54d51a72c

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to store/print success mail count into a JSON format.

```
import smtplib
import SSL
import json
import os
from email.mime.text import MIMEText  # New line
from email.utils import formataddr  # New line

fileName = "sendMail_count.json"
# To store data into json file.
# It will create file in datetime format.
def store_data_to_file(jsonStr):
    jsonFile = open(fileName, "w")
    json.dump(jsonStr, jsonFile)
    print("data stored successfully")

# User configuration
sender_email = 'email ID'
sender_name = 'name'
password = "password"

receiver_emails = [RECEIVER_EMAIL_1, RECEIVER_EMAIL_2, RECEIVER_EMAIL_3]
receiver_names = [RECEIVER_NAME_1, RECEIVER_NAME_2, RECEIVER_NAME_3]

# To store the count of successful mail received by receiver with their respective email.
if not os.path.exists(fileName) or os.stat(fileName).st_size == 0:
    print("File is empty or not found")
    print("Creating a JSON file to store the data")
    jsonFile = open(fileName, "w+")
    print("a JSON file has been created with name: " + str(fileName))
    success_mail_count = {}
else:
    with open(fileName) as jsonFile:
        success_mail_count = json.load(jsonFile)
    print(success_mail_count)

# Email text
email_body = '''
    This is a test email sent by Python. Isn't that cool?
'''

for receiver_email, receiver_name in zip(receiver_emails, receiver_names):
    count = 0
    print("Sending the email to..." + receiver_email)

    # Configurating user's info
    msg = MIMEText(email_body, 'plain')
    msg['To'] = formataddr((receiver_name, receiver_email))
    msg['From'] = formataddr((sender_name, sender_email))
    msg['Subject'] = 'Hello, my friend ' + receiver_name

    try:
        # Creating a SMTP session | use 587 with TLS, 465 SSL and 25
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        # Encrypts the email
        context = ssl.create_default_context()
        server.starttls(context=context)
        # We log in into our Google account
        server.login(sender_email, password)
        # Sending email from sender, to receiver with the email body
        server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, msg.as_string())

        # Check if recevier is already present in the dict, 
        # then add 1 to its current count
        if receiver_email in success_mail_count:
            success_mail_count[receiver_email] = str(int(success_mail_count[receiver_email]) + 1)
        # If reciever isn't present in map then create new entry for receiver and 
        # Update the count with one for successfull mail sent.
        else:
            success_mail_count[receiver_email] = str(count + 1)

        print('Email sent!')

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Oh no! Something bad happened!n {e}')

    finally:
        print('Closing the server...')
        server.quit()

print(success_mail_count)

store_data_to_file(success_mail_count)
```

run this code and it will create data into file and then it will read data from file itself.

Comment: Hi, so this worked to a certain effect, similar to the another answer. I was wondering if there is a way to count up the successful email sent to each ID. For eg: Let's say the script sends email to "abc@email.com" twice. So it should reflect 2. And then once again it sends successfully so the count should increase to 3 and so on. Currently, it shows just 1 for each iteration. Also, I wanted to save the count to Google sheet. How can i convert the number to a string format which can be saved easily in Google sheet.

Comment: Hi, i suggest you to store the data into file for further calculation, i have modified my code.

Comment: output will look something like this:
{'RECEIVER_EMAIL_1': '5', 'RECEIVER_EMAIL_2': '5', 'RECEIVER_EMAIL_3': '5'}

Comment: Hi, this is just saving the last email address in the JSON file. Also, it's not incrementing with each run of the script. I tried shifting the last part of the code i.e. `print(success_mail_count)
# if you want to store data into file you can use this funtion
store_data_to_file(success_mail_count)`

to `finally:` block. Over there it was just overwriting each email address rather than appending a new line with new email id. Also, it wasn't incrementing over here.

Comment: I have updated the code please check once. I have tried 4 to 5 time in my local and it creating the data in file and updating the count in file.

Comment: Hi, this worked as well. But now I am wondering how can I transfer values from the JSON to a Google Sheet directly from the script or save the values directly to a Google Sheet instead of the JSON file? Any suggestion or direction you can point me towards? I have tried looking around. I haven't found any suitable answers for it.

Comment: you can refer this https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-read-and-write-data-to-google-spreadsheet-using-python-ebf54d51a72c link for reference.